# how to get .framework file without containing dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, dependency-management

I have a closed source framework as a project in Xcode that has several dependencies. and I want to make it available throw Cocoapods, so I need to upload a .framework file and specify a path to it in podspec. right? the problem is when I use the .framework file in products, it appears that it containts dependencies. and that's really bad, cus I specify those dependencies in podspec and after installing my cocoapod and running the app, user sees something like this in his/her console:

```
objc[7021]: Class GPBAnyRoot is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55E220B9-0CF6-4FA3-8B95-9DE798053191/PodTest3.app/Frameworks/Pushe.framework/Pushe (0x10578e3d8) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55E220B9-0CF6-4FA3-8B95-9DE798053191/PodTest3.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf (0x1055f6ca0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7021]: Class GPBAny is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55E220B9-0CF6-4FA3-8B95-9DE798053191/PodTest3.app/Frameworks/Pushe.framework/Pushe (0x10578e400) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55E220B9-0CF6-4FA3-8B95-9DE798053191/PodTest3.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf (0x1055f6cc8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7021]: Class GPBApiRoot is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55E220B9-0CF6-4FA3-8B95-9DE798053191/PodTest3.app/Frameworks/Pushe.framework/Pushe (0x10578e478) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/55E220B9-0CF6-4FA3-8B95-9DE798053191/PodTest3.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf (0x1055f6d40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

so how can I get a clean .framework file without dependencies? I searched and tried a lot and didn't find a clean step by step solution for making a pod with closed source code and inner dependencies.

Comment: Link the framework's library statically instead of dynamically.

Comment: Can you please answer more specific, or maybe use some example for being more clear?